# Move Files From One Directory to Another Using Shell Script

Tags: shell, sh

I have written a shell script which moves all the files from a specific directory to another directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Command to execute
execute_cmd=mv

path=/home/ypsvc/sa_automation

# Files inside actual_dir has to be moved
actual_dir="$path/sa_cx_data"

# This is the directory where files will be moved and kept
backup_dir="$path/file_backup/"

# Move each file from actual_dir to backup_dir

echo "Moving files to backup_dir"

for f in $actual_dir/*.xlsx
# echo f
do
 $execute_cmd "$f" $backup_dir
done

echo "Moving of files completed"
```

But when I run this, it gives below error:

```
Moving files to backup_dir
: not found.sh: 14: file_backup.sh:
file_backup.sh: 16: file_backup.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Can someone help in resolving this?

PS: **file_backup** is already created and proper permission has been given to the script.

Running the script with -x gives below result:

```
+
: not found.sh: 2: file_backup.sh:
+ execute_cmd=mv
+
: not found.sh: 5: file_backup.sh:
+ path=/home/ypsvc/sa_automation
+
: not found.sh: 7: file_backup.sh:
/sa_cx_datar=/home/ypsvc/sa_automation
+
: not found.sh: 10: file_backup.sh:
/file_backup//home/ypsvc/sa_automation
+
: not found.sh: 13: file_backup.sh:
+
: not found.sh: 15: file_backup.sh:
+ echo Moving files to backup_dir
Moving files to backup_dir
+
: not found.sh: 17: file_backup.sh:
file_backup.sh: 20: file_backup.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Comment: FYI: paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, it will point out some improvements.

Comment: @Nic3500 not a good option for this

Comment: It is not a solution, therefore I did not put it as an answer.

Comment: @Sumit: I don't think you have posted the exact script which causes the trouble, because the line numbers in the error messages don't correspond to the lines you have posted. Run the script with `-x` and let us know the output.

Comment: Try adding double quotes: `$execute_cmd "$f" $backup_dir`

Comment: The command variable and the loop are basically useless, you can just `mv "$actual_dir"/*.xlsx "$backup_dir"`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
#!/bin/bash

# Command to execute
execute_cmd=mv

path="/home/ypsvc/sa_automation"

# Files inside actual_dir has to be moved
actual_dir="$path/sa_cx_data"

# This is the directory where files will be moved and kept
backup_dir="$path/file_backup/"

# Move each file from actual_dir to backup_dir

echo "Moving files to backup_dir"

for f in $(find $actual_dir -type f -name *.xlsx); ## used find here, with semicolon
do
 echo $f
 $execute_cmd $f $backup_dir
done

echo "Moving of files completed"
```

Comment: I tried, but it gives same error!

Comment: @Sumit this worked for me, as i have tested this. Please check with other things. Like version and all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one , should work

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/ypsvc/sa_automation"
# Files inside actual_dir has to be moved
actual_dir="$path/sa_cx_data"
find $path -name '*.xlsx' -exec mv {} $actual_dir \;
```

Comment: You probably mean : find $path -name '*.xlsx' -exec mv {} $actual_dir \;